# ElasticSearch set-like (unique list of values) functionality?

Tags: elasticsearch, set

Does ElasticSearch support set-like functionality with its [array data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-array-type.html)?

I want to be able to write to an array multiple types and enforce uniqueness on array values.

In other words, I'm looking for something like Redis' [SADD](http://redis.io/commands/SADD) or MongoDB's [addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) but for ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [scripted updates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_scripted_updates).

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/1/_update' -d '{
    "script" : "ctx._source.tags.contains(tag) ? (ctx.op = \"none\") : ctx._source.tags += tag"
    "params" : {
        "tag" : "blue"
    }
}'
```

Mind that there are a number of limitations on scripting in Elasticsearch for security reasons; you might want to check the [Scripting module page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html) in the docs.

Comment: using scripted updates with an array isn't the same speed as a set tho